# Correctness properties, judgments and rules

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, parsing

Definition: sD means $s$ is a digit, i.e. $s$ is one of $0,1,\dots,9$. 
k Nat means $k\in\bf N$.

Proposition: If sD <-> k Nat then sD and k Nat.

I don't really understand what I have to prove. Do I have to prove that ¬SD and ¬k Nat isn't possible? 
The hint I was given is to use induction but I don't see how.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what you mean by s, D, <->, k, and Nat? Is s D the same as SD?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - would you mind clarifying the question, and adding definitions for s D and k Nat?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I have already added the definitions, the topic is Parsing with judgments, subject: Programming languages

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I have added them

Comment: So, your Proposition is, If "$s$ is a digit" is equivalent to "$k$ is a natural number", then $s$ is a digit, and $k$ is a natural number. Is that right? If so, what is your question? Are you asked to prove that the Proposition is true? or to decide whether the Proposition is true? Are you meant to work in some formal system, or just to reason informally? Much clarification still needed.

Answer (score 1):

With the information that you provided in your question, from a logical point of view the implication mentioned in your question is false.

What you could prove is that

(sD⇔k Nat)⇒((sD∧k Nat)∨(¬(sD)∧¬(k Nat)))

That is

¬(sD⇔k Nat)∨(sD∧k Nat)∨(¬(sD)∧¬(k Nat))

¬((sD⇒k Nat)∧(k Nat⇒sD))∨(sD∧k Nat)∨(¬(sD)∧¬(k Nat))

¬((¬(sD)∨(k Nat))∧(¬(k Nat)∨(sD)))∨
(sD∧k Nat)∨(¬(sD)∧¬(k Nat))

(sD∧¬(k Nat))∨(k Nat ∧¬(sD))∨(sD∧k Nat)∨(¬(sD)∧¬(k Nat))

The last statement is true because s could be a digit or not, k could be a natural number or not, and the statement above covers all 4 possible combinations.